# How to have in code documentation in KivyMD?

Tags: pycharm, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm with the obstacle that in KiivyMD using **Pycharm** I have no support to know the properties, I know that have a Kivy suggestion, as this:
[image: Suggestion_Kivy]
when using KivyMD currently it is necessary to stop everything , go in the documentation and keep consulting every time you forget. would like to have some kind of documentation, but in kivyMD, in the code, as it is done in python?:
[image: Like this]
if anyone knows a way that is possible this, because this current way is really slow to do something. If there isn't I'd like to create this manually